# How to make this function also move pixels to the left?

Tags: image, image-processing, rust

The following code moves non-transparent pixels one position to the right (x axis):

```
use image::{DynamicImage, GenericImageView, ImageBuffer};

fn move_pixels_right(img: &DynamicImage, shift: u32) -> DynamicImage {
    let (width, height) = img.dimensions();
    let mut new_img = ImageBuffer::new(width, height);

    for y in 0..height {
        for x in shift..width {
            let pixel = img.get_pixel(x - shift, y);
            new_img.put_pixel(x, y, pixel);
        }
    }

    DynamicImage::ImageRgba8(new_img)
}

fn main() {
    let img = image::open("center.png").unwrap();
    let moved_img = move_pixels_right(&img, 1);

    moved_img.save("moved.png").unwrap();
}
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

As you can see, the function only works if you want to move the pixels to the right. How to modify it so that you can also move pixels to the left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can allow shifting in either direction by changing `shift` to `i32` (so it can support negatives) and changing the bounds like so:

```
for y in 0..height {
    let left = i32::max(0, shift);
    let right = i32::min(0, shift) + width as i32;
    for x in left..right {
        let pixel = img.get_pixel((x - shift) as u32, y);
        new_img.put_pixel(x as u32, y, pixel);
    }
}
```

A `shift` of `5` will shift the image five to the right, while a `shift` of `-5` will shift the image five to the left.